# c# System.Data.SQLite parameters error

Tags: c#, parameters, system.data.sqlite

I am using SQlite database on C# and have an error issue with parameters.

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
```

Here is a main code part:

```
            this.dbUpdateCommand = new SQLiteCommand();

            dbUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramNewValue", (string)this.valueNew);
            dbUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramPredValue", (string)this.valuePred);
            dbUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramTableName", (string) this.tableName);
            dbUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramColumnName", (string)this.columnInDB);
            dbUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramKeyField", (string)this.keyFieldInDB);
            dbUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramKeyValue", (string)this.keyValueInDB);

            dbUpdateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE @paramTableName SET @paramColumnName=@paramNewValue WHERE @paramKeyField=@paramKeyValue;";

            dbUpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And it throws me exception "SQLite error near "@paramTableName": syntax error"

I tried to make pure SQL statement without params but with strings concatenation and it works with the same variables (this.tableName is valid db tablename) 
So it seems something wrong with my parameters. Does anybody knows, what?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use parameters to reference objects (tables & columns).  You would need to drop the actual table and column names into your query.  Be careful of SQL injection while doing so.